# "Cannot set property style of #<Element> which has only a getter in [null]" thrown by Angular 2 on Some browsers

Tags: angular

I'm running application with angular 2- v beta 9

It works on most of the browser but for some browser gives following error:

```
Uncaught EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot set property style of #<Element> which has only a getter in [null]
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot set property style of #<Element> which has only a getter
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
TypeError: Cannot set property style of #<Element> which has only a getter
    at BrowserDomAdapter.setProperty (http://..../static/build/common.js:24017:86)
    at DomRenderer.setElementProperty (http://..../static/build/common.js:23263:28)
    at AppView.notifyOnBinding (http://..../static/build/common.js:15231:32)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.notifyDispatcher (http://..../static/build/common.js:11174:26)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.ChangeDetector_Dashboard_0.detectChangesInRecordsInternal (viewFactory_Dashboard:150:14)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.detectChangesInRecords (http://..../static/build/common.js:11070:19)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.runDetectChanges (http://..../static/build/common.js:11047:15)
    at AbstractChangeDetector._detectChangesInViewChildren (http://..../static/build/common.js:11147:19)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.runDetectChanges (http://..../static/build/common.js:11051:15)
    at AbstractChangeDetector._detectChangesContentChildren (http://..../static/build/common.js:11140:19)
ERROR CONTEXT:
[object Object]
```

Comment: Can you reproduce in a Plunker? Did this code work in a previous version?

Comment: Yes it worked in previous version and most of the browser

Comment: And now it's only failing in specific browsers or in all. I guess you need to show some code.

Comment: The file is too big around 6 mb So I can not attach here but link to file on gdrive is follows

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-A5IGT5OHCpZVBYWU5JaG1fTWs/view?usp=sharing